# Употребление слова "успоряешь"

Tags: выбор-слов

Регулярно слышу неприятное слово "успоряешь". 
Произносится оно в значении "оспариваешь", "споришь".
Не могу предположить, что слово используется знакомыми, так как слышала его в разных компаниях и организациях г. Тамбова.

Comment: «Успорять» очень активно использовалось и в Амурской области, но не в значении «спорить», а в значении «утверждать». Я его просто воспринимала как просторечное. Мне оно по детским играм знакомо.

Answer (score 1):

Слово "успорять" живёт в русских диалектах, то есть нормативным не является.

См. подборочку из "рязанского языка" (диалектные слова Рязанской области):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кликаем по глаголу "[успорять](http://rjaz.net/news/2010-10)":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слово найдено также в монументальном труде ["МОТИВАЦИОННЫЙ СЛОВАРЬ
СИБИРСКОГО ГОВОРА"](http://file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B/Downloads/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0.pdf):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот фрагмент текста из ["Хазарских писаний"](http://legarhan.narod.ru/MAAT-01.htm):

> Мелхицедэк же поднялся с седалища своего и сказал: "Будет ли кто
>   успорять из вас, что любовь правит миром сиим? Верно говорю вам, -
>   никто не успорит! Ибо что есть любовь, как не воплощение Света
>   Божьего, и что есть Свет Божий, как не воплощение Духа?! Будет ли кто
>   успорять из вас, что во Господе нашем не сопряжены обе ипостаси
>   соительствующие? Верно говорю вам, - никто не успорит! Человек же
>   выстроен по образу и подобию Господнему и лишь по кровожадности своей
>   подразделен на мужа и жену. Иначе б не сподобился рождаться. Будет ли
>   кто успорять из вас, что Бог Единый неволен во деяниях Своих? Верно
>   говорю вам, - никто не успорит! Отсего мы, чада Его единородные,
>   своевольны под сводом закона вселенского.

Answer (score 0):

По-видимому, это слово принадлежит рязанской группе говоров (т.е. уместно только локально и в устной речи):

http://rjaz.net/news/usporjat/2010-10-21-446

От Рязани до Тамбова примерно 240 км; области соприкасаются ещё ближе.

Comment: Скажу вам больше: Инжавинский район Тамбовской области заселили выходцы из Рязани.